# Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?

Tags: css, вёрстка

[image: Блоки]

Подскажите как такое сверстать. Интересует именно блоки в виде трапеций с обводкой. Фон, стрелки, текст - то все понятно.

Comment: если хорошо помучатся, то 3d трансформации и с текстом можно оформить красиво

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я предлагаю вашему вниманию альтернативное решение.

**Из минусов:**

- поскольку смещение и ширина срезов вычисляется не по математической формуле, а "на глазок", есть небольшой косячок на границе в левом верхнем углу блока.
- лишняя разметка
- в примере нет префиксов

**Из плюсов:**

- на текст нет никакого влияния.

---

**Основная идея:**

С помощью псевдоэлементов и дополнительной разметки мы можем "срезать" лишнее с краев прямоугольника, чтобы превратить его в трапецию.
Чтобы получился не просто срез, а граница блока, будем использовать два одинаковых по размеру блока разного цвета, разместив их один над другим с небольшим смещением.

---

**Реализация:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Обертка нужна для обрезки "лишнего" в разметке */

.wrapper {  
  margin: 0 20px;
  max-width: 510px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* трапеция*/

.item {
  border: 2px solid #606060;
  height: 120px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* Чтобы текст не залезал на наши будущие срезы */
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

/* Перекрашиваем четные трапеции */

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background: #606060;
  color: #fff;
}
/* Подложки, для имитации границы */

.item::before,
.item::after,
.item .border {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Нижний слой подложки для цвета границы */

.item::before,
.item::after {
  background: #606060;
  top: 0;
}

/* Верхний слой подложки для "среза" прямоугольника */

.item .border {
  background: #fff;
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  top: -2px;
}

/* Наклон среза для четных трапеций */

.item:nth-child(odd)::before,
.item:nth-child(odd)::after,
.item:nth-child(odd) .border.left {
  transform: skew(10deg);
}

.item:nth-child(odd)::after,
.item:nth-child(odd) .border.right {
  transform: skew(-10deg);
}

/* Наклон среза для нечетных трапеций */

.item:nth-child(even)::before,
.item:nth-child(even)::after,
.item:nth-child(even) .border.left {
  transform: skew(-10deg);
}

.item:nth-child(even)::after,
.item:nth-child(even) .border.right {
  transform: skew(10deg);
}

/**
 * Выравниваем нижний и верхний слой подложки друг относительно друга
 * Учитываем левый и правый срез
 */

.item::before {
  left: -70px;
}
.item .border.left {
  left: -72px;
}
.item::after {
  right: -70px;
}
.item .border.right {
  right: -72px;
}

/**
 * ::after всегда последний, поэтому надо выставить z-index для правого верхнего слоя
 */

.item .border.right {
  z-index: 1;
}

/**
 * Максимум 5 строчек текста
 * Вместо отображения скролла текст можно прятать
 */

.item > .text {
  line-height: 20px;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="border left"></div>
    <div class="text">Пример контента</div>
    <div class="border right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="border left"></div>
    <div class="text">Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a.</div>
    <div class="border right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="border left"></div>
    <div class="text">Здесь что-то написано</div>
    <div class="border right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/bwmOQy?editors=110  тоже самое,если в первый item текста больше чем строчка в 5 слов получается косяк , вечером приду с работы и попробую

Comment: @Geyan по скриншоту фиксированная высота. Какова ваша задача?

Comment: @Geyan, я добавил вариант с полосой прокрутки и указал, как обойтись без нее. Это решает вашу задачу?

Comment: не мою идею , я в сети где то когда то видел вообще суперское решение как раз на эту тему , но к сожалению потерял ссылку , и я б на тему css не задавал вопрос

Comment: и тоже шляпа получилась : http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/EgONmb?editors=1100

Comment: @Geyan не вижу проблемы. И что не картинкой-то?)

Answer (score 13):

```css
.trapezoid-in {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(-1deg);
  margin: 6px 50px 0;
}

.trapezoid-out {
  border: 2px solid #555;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
  transform: perspective(15px) rotateX(1deg);
  margin: -6px 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid-in"></div>
<div class="trapezoid-out"></div>
<div class="trapezoid-in"></div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/amRPaJ?editors=110  что  получится  если добавить  текст

Comment: @Geyan > *Интересует именно блоки в виде трапеций с обводкой. Фон, стрелки, текст - то все понятно.* - вопрос был про блоки.. А чтоб текст красиво отображался - нужен внутренний блок, развернуть его обратно внешнему, ну и конечно текста меньше (или блоки сделать больше) - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAzvZv

Answer (score 5):

Еще как вариант

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.b-trapezoid {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #606060;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.b-trapezoid:before,
.b-trapezoid:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border: 2px solid #606060;
}
.b-trapezoid:before,
.b-trapezoid:nth-of-type(even):before {
  top: -2px;
  left: -7px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(7deg);
  transform: skew(7deg);
  border-right: none;
}
.b-trapezoid:after,
.b-trapezoid:nth-of-type(even):after {
  top: -2px;
  right: -7px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-7deg);
  transform: skew(-7deg);
  border-left: none;
}
.b-trapezoid:nth-of-type(even),
.b-trapezoid:nth-of-type(even):before,
.b-trapezoid:nth-of-type(even):after {
  background: #606060;
  color: #fff;
}
.b-trapezoid:nth-of-type(even):before {
  -webkit-transform: skew(-7deg);
  transform: skew(-7deg);
  border-left: none;
}
.b-trapezoid:nth-of-type(even):after {
  -webkit-transform: skew(7deg);
  transform: skew(7deg);
  border-right: none;
}
.b-trapezoid-content {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
.b-trapezoid-content-item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.b-trapezoid-content-text {
  max-height: 75px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.b-trapezoid-content-text::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}
.b-trapezoid-content-text::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 0;
}
.b-trapezoid-content-text::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background: #ccc;
}
.b-trapezoid-content-text::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #4682B4;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <div class="b-trapezoid">
    <div class="b-trapezoid-content">
      <div class="b-trapezoid-content-item">
        <div class="b-trapezoid-content-text">
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-trapezoid">
    <div class="b-trapezoid-content">
      <div class="b-trapezoid-content-item">
        <div class="b-trapezoid-content-text">
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-trapezoid">
    <div class="b-trapezoid-content">
      <div class="b-trapezoid-content-item">
        <div class="b-trapezoid-content-text">
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-trapezoid">
    <div class="b-trapezoid-content">
      <div class="b-trapezoid-content-item">
        <div class="b-trapezoid-content-text">
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-trapezoid">
    <div class="b-trapezoid-content">
      <div class="b-trapezoid-content-item">
        <div class="b-trapezoid-content-text">
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
          <p>Как добиться эффекта сложенного гармошкой листа с помощью CSS?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поставил плюс за альтернативную идею и аккуратную реализацию

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/PGyXXX?editors=110  после добавления текста , блоки сыпятся - трапезоиды - но решение  лучше двух выше